# Как подключить роутер к свитчу?

Tags: сеть, администрирование, lan, локальная-сеть

Имеется модем, в него заходит оптика, от него идет LAN кабель на свитч. Сам модем еще и раздает вайфай. Можно ли подключить еще один WiFi роутер к свитчу, чтобы он раздавал собственный WiFi и при этом к нему подключить по LAN кабелю 2 компьютера, чтобы у них был доступ к общей сети (к клиентам, которые подключены к свитчу). Как это можно реализовать и какие настройки сделать на роутере?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]